# AngularJS $resource - 414 Request-URI Too Large

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angularjs-resource

I use AngularJS $resource to save large objects. Everything worked good, until object became really large.

```
angular.module('Test.services').factory('TestService', function($resource) {

    return $resource( '/MyRestURL/:id', { id: "@id" }, {
        save : {
            method: 'POST',
            isArray: false,
            params: {
                data: "@data"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

I get response

```
Method  POST
Cached  No
Status  Request-URI Too Large
Code    414
```

And I see it sends everything in URL...

Comment: With what browser happened. I would assume IE and if so what version?

Comment: I'd remove the `params`, because I think _that_ makes angular put all the data in the url, whereas you just want to post it.

Comment: @towr - genius!!! How can I mark your comment as best answer:)?

Comment: Dalorzo - browser was Safari.

Comment: @ArūnasSmaliukas I'll post it as a proper answer (actually, I already have)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
angular.module('Test.services').factory('TestService', function($resource) {
    return $resource( '/MyRestURL/:id', { id: "@id" }, {
        save : {
            method: 'POST'
        }
});
```

The `params` tell angular to put that property in the url as get parameter. (And the `isArray` is false by default.)